# parameterize distribution of subsets

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, parameterization

Suppose there is a set $S=\{1, 2, 3, ..., n\}$, then I need a distribution of its subsets with fixed size k, which can be denoted as $A=\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_k\}$ where $x_1$ to $x_k$ are from 1 to n.

This distribution can be defined on each subset that $P(A)$ is the probability to choose subset A. But the free parameters are too many to deal with. It will be preferable that free variables is in an order of $O(n)$ or a small polynomial of $O(n)$. The point probability should be calculated within a small polynomial of $O(n)$ time complexity, and we can sample from this distribution efficiently.

For example, we can define as in [Sample subsets with distribution proportional to elementwise product](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401071/sample-subsets-with-distribution-proportional-to-elementwise-product)

but when we want to calculate the point probability or sample a subset, we should go over all subset and calculate their value then normalize, which is $O$(number of subsets) not $O(n)$.

The answer to this question should provide a formal definition of the distribution and provide an efficient method to calculate its point probability and an efficient sample method.

Comment: Almost any probabilistic procedure to sample without replacement will satisfy all your criteria.  Could you be more specific about what distribution you need or what the application is?

Comment: @whuber Not exactly, when you sample without replacement, you sampled a permutation and you only have the probability of this permutation, not the subset. To get the probability of the subset you should marginalize all permutation of this subset.

Comment: That's correct, but in many cases the marginalization is easy to compute.  Please see any textbook of sampling, such as Thompson's *Sampling.*

Comment: @whuber Thanks, I'm not very familiar with sampling, but I think in sampling there must be a tradeoff between precision and efficiency, so it may not be a preferable solution if there (maybe) is an exact approach. Indeed I want to calculate kl divergence of two such distribution and optimize them, where I need an exact parameterized form to calculate the gradient. Because It's hard to calculate the kl divergence directly I think it's ok to approximate by sampling, however, the point probability should be exact.

Comment: I warmly recommend consulting the literature, because the objective behind sampling theories is optimization of some measure of the statistical value of the data to be collected.  Thompson's book is for practitioners, and so is relatively untheoretical, but it also includes clear mathematical accounts of the underlying theory for those who are interested.

Comment: @whuber Thanks again for your kind help. However, I'm in China and Thompson's book is not available. I have opened a new question with a more specific configuration, would you please give a more detailed answer under that one? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/442815/kl-divergence-of-two-different-distributions-of-subsets